# remove dollar sign from string

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

This one got me puzzled

Trying to remove a dollar sign from a string proved to be impossible,
whats wrong here ?

Here is what i have to work with:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "$18.95" [1]=> string(11) " $17.06" }
```

this is what i have tried

1. `floatval($price[0]);`
2. `str_replace('$','',$price[0]);`
3. `ltrim($price[0],'$');`
4. `floatval(ltrim($price[0],'$'));`
5. `floatval(preg_replace("/^[^0-9\.]/","",$price[0]))`

the only close one was

```
floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $price[0]))
```

but it added "36" to the number - insteadh of 18.95 i got 3618.95

nothing is working ... why ?

`

Comment: `$price = str_replace('$','',$price[0]);` is not working?

Comment: Will every single record have the dollar sign? Why not just use a [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove the first character?

Comment: `$price[0] = str_replace('$','',$price[0]);` ?

Comment: Your str_replace should work. So something else is wrong in your code.

Comment: problem was it wasn't a real dollar sign but an html representation of it (&#36;) - doesn't var_dump supposed to know that and show it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You said:

> floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $price[0])) 
> but it added "36"
>   to the number - insteadh of 18.95 i got 3618.95

It comes in my mind that you doesn't have a `$` sign in front of your values but `&#36;` that is the representation of `$`.

In order to see if my guess is correct, print the array in a terminal instead of a browser. Or look at the source of the page.

In this case, you could do:

```
$val = preg_replace('/&#36;/', '', $val);
```

or, more generalist:

```
$val = preg_replace('/&.*?;/', '', $val);
```

Answer (score 4):

This one works well:

```
$input   = "$18.95";
$output  = floatval(ltrim($input, '$'));
$output += 36;
```

Output:

```
float 54.95
```

Comment: Be careful, doesn't work when $input is negative. Eg -$18.95.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems with Unicode support (weird symbols appearing using `substr`) this will work if the symbol is always first.

```
$var = ltrim($price[0],'$')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
    $price = '$12.00';
    $var = str_replace('$','',$price);
    echo $var;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the $ will always be in the first position, a simple and efficient

```
substr($string,1);
```

should do the job

Comment: this is what i got array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "#36;18.95" [1]=> string(9) "#36;17.06" }

Comment: This should work, but I think unicode support is probably getting in the way.  I've seen this fail, although it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<?php

$price = array( "0"=> "$18.95", "1"=> " $17.06" );
foreach($price as $key=>$value) {
    $price[$key] = trim(str_replace('$','',$value));
}
print_r($price);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18.95
    [1] => 17.06
)
```

Comment: didnt work for me - i got array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "$18.95" [1]=> string(10) "$17.06" }

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace()

```
// Provides: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php